# User32.dll!NtUserWindowFromPoint getting corrupt when loaded by Mumble on Windows RT

Tags: windows, qt, corruption, user32, windows-rt

I'm working on porting Mumble over to Windows RT (using the jailbreak), and I've hit an issue where this one function is getting corrupted when Mumble loads.

Mumble (Corrupt function):

> 0:000> dq user32.dll+0x023918
>   77a63918  47c30042`44696841 4770df01`0c16f241
>   77a63928  4770df01`0c17f241 4770df01`0c18f241
>   77a63938  4770df01`0c19f241 4770df01`0c1af241
>   77a63948  4770df01`0c1bf241 4770df01`0c1cf241
>   77a63958  4770df01`0c1df241 4770df01`0c1ef241
>   77a63968  4770df01`0c1ff241 4770df01`5c81f44f
>   77a63978  4770df01`0c21f241 4770df01`0c22f241
>   77a63988  4770df01`0c23f241 4770df01`0c24f241
>   0:000> u user32.dll+0x023918
>   *** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for 
>   C:\windows\system32\user32.dll -
>   user32!WindowFromPoint:
>   77a63918 6841     ldr         r1,[r0,#4]
>   77a6391a 4469     add         r1,r1,sp
>   77a6391c 0042     lsls        r2,r0,#1
>   77a6391e 47c3     ?blx        r8
>   77a63920 f2410c16 mov         r12,#0x1016
>   77a63924 df01     svc         #1

TeXworks (Expected output):

> 0:000> dq user32.dll+0x23918
>   77a63918  4770df01`0c15f241 4770df01`0c16f241
>   77a63928  4770df01`0c17f241 4770df01`0c18f241
>   77a63938  4770df01`0c19f241 4770df01`0c1af241
>   77a63948  4770df01`0c1bf241 4770df01`0c1cf241
>   77a63958  4770df01`0c1df241 4770df01`0c1ef241
>   77a63968  4770df01`0c1ff241 4770df01`5c81f44f
>   77a63978  4770df01`0c21f241 4770df01`0c22f241
>   77a63988  4770df01`0c23f241 4770df01`0c24f241
>   0:000> u user32.dll+0x23918
>   *** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\windows\system32\USER32.dll -
>   USER32!WindowFromPoint:
>   77a63918 f2410c15 mov         r12,#0x1015
>   77a6391c df01     svc         #1
>   77a6391e 4770     bx          lr
>   77a63920 f2410c16 mov         r12,#0x1016
>   77a63924 df01     svc         #1
>   77a63926 4770     bx          lr
>   77a63928 f2410c17 mov         r12,#0x1017
>   77a6392c df01     svc         #1

(Apologies for the less than stellar formatting of the code, a screenshot of the windows can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yybVA.png )

Mumble uses Qt (customized by the Mumble team, to my understanding), Protobuf, Boost, and OpenSSL
TeXworks uses Qt

What I've tried so far:
Disabling the application compatibility engine
Unloading user32.dll at load, then reloading it (calling FreeLibrary 100 times, then calling LoadLibrary)
Removing anything that might look even remotely suspect from the manifests (from Qt and Mumble)
Removing the entire manifests (from Qt and Mumble)

If I patch this one function using cdb after Mumble launches it all works awesomely, but if I don't patch it the first action performed that calls that function ends in a crash. Opening/closing windows and dragging all call that function, so it's rather critical to the program that it's there.

Any help or pointers on this would be more than appreciated.

Edit: I've verified that it's something inside mainCRTStartup that's mucking around with it, trying to figure out what exactly it is now.

Edit 2: Found a platform-specific hook hidden in the Mumble code that was causing my troubles. Solved.

Comment: "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 1 hour. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can finally answer this now, Mumble had some hooks hidden away that I didn't know about. I defined a custom entrypoint that called mainCRTStartup so I could step through that and find exactly where that memory was getting changed, it led me straight to the hook.

Here's the code I used for that:

```
EXTERN_C int WINAPI mainCRTStartup();
void __stdcall EntryPoint()
{
    MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP,L"Pause(Before mainCRTStartup)",L"Pause(Before mainCRTStartup",MB_OK);
    mainCRTStartup();
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

That allowed me to attach a debugger at the messagebox and step through mainCRTStartup until I found the static initializer that was getting called to load the hook.